# applied shopping cart rule information display in product view page

Tags: shopping-cart-price-rules

I created simple shopping cart rule(using Discount Qty Step (Buy X)) for all products.its working fine in shopping cart.For user awareness I have written following code.

I created one function in Mage_Salesrule_Model_Validator

```
public function petdreamsrule($rule, $address=null, $myitem)
    {
       //$val=Mage::getModel('salesrule/validator');
        if ($this->_canProcessRule($rule, $address) && $rule->getActions()->validate($myitem)) {
               // var_dump($rule);
               return $rule;
            }
    }
```

and I'm calling in deafult.phtml(design.checkout/cart/item/) like this

```
<?php  
            $rules = Mage::getResourceModel('salesrule/rule_collection')->load();
            foreach ($rules as $rule) {
                if ($rule->getIsActive()) {
                    $rule = Mage::getModel('salesrule/rule')->load($rule->getId());
                    $val=Mage::getModel('salesrule/validator');
                    $ruleinfo= $val->petdreamsrule($rule, $address=null ,$_item);
                    if($ruleinfo){
                        $ourdiscount=$ruleinfo->getDiscountAmount();
                        $breakqty=$ruleinfo->getDiscountStep();
}}}
```

upto this point working fine.

But i need to call same function in product view page.I'm getting null for ruleinfo.anyone can guide how to do it?

Comment: Did you find any solution? I need to validate 'salesrule' on list & view page.

Comment: I assume the issue here is that on the product page you are passing the product but the validator needs a quote item

Answer (score 1):

The problem here I think is that you are working on the product page so you are passing a product to the validator but the validator expects a quote item and not a product.